# IBM Extended ASCII Characters in HTML

Tags: html, character-encoding, character, ascii, dos

I'm trying to get special characters into HTML, and am not sure if this is even possible. If anyone remembers Kroz, or just about every DOS interface - there is a special set of shape characters. I'm wanting to use the single braces, double braces, shadows, and other shape characters, but I can't seem to track any of these down anywhere.

[image]

Also, will using these characters in an HTML environment present any localization concerns / will there be a required charset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no “extended ASCII”; ASCII ends at code position 127 decimal, 7F hexadecimal. What is called “extended ASCII” is a set of mutually incompatible 8-bit encodings that contain the printable ASCII characters in the same positions as in ASCII. In your case, you seem to want to use the Code Page 437. All of its characters exist in Unicode. You can find the correspondence at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437
which I believe to be correct in this issue; but the authoritative reference is
http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT

There are various ways to enter the characters. You can use, say, “▓” as such in HTML, if you have some way of entering it and you use UTF-8 on the page. Alternatively, you can use character references like `&#x2593;`.

Comment: Thank you! Every time I came across the characters online they were referred to as Extended ASCII and all of the lists of special characters conveniently left out the box drawing characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, similar characters exist in the UTF-8 character set. These are called *box drawing* characters.

See: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/box_drawing/utf8test.htm